# Better hillshading for map plots in R

Tags: r, gis

I'm working on improved hillshading for some topographical map plots.  The basic hillshade workflow documented in `image()` is:

```
require(raster)
alt = getData('alt', country='CHE')
slope = terrain(alt, opt='slope')
aspect = terrain(alt, opt='aspect')
hill = hillShade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, main='Switzerland')
plot(alt, col=rainbow(25, alpha=0.35), add=TRUE)
```

This image shows `plot(hill..)` before `plot(alt..)` is applied:

[image]

The method creates a solid grey under-layer of hillshades on which other data layers (e.g. elevation shading) are plotted semi-transparently.  The problem with this approach is (a) that the neutral colour for flat terrain (RBG (202,202,202), '#CACACA') severely shades the whole model, which (b) prevents multiple shade layering, such as used by the ['Swiss hillshade'](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/10/07/updated-hillshade-toolbox/) approach.

I can imagine an workaround that converts rasters to matrices and applies hillshading as a numerical multiplier to the brightness of other layers, but this doesn't seem very elegant (although I may be wrong).  I wonder if anyone has any ideas or (preferably) experience in this area?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: so @geotheory you make any headway on this since posing the question? Feel free to post an answer as well if you've got something slick working.

Comment: Not yet Tim, and I apologise for getting sidetracked. Have accepted your answer. I'll post anything here you guys might find useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No experience with this, but why not give the gray undermap an alpha value that depends on slopes? Here's my try:

```
# before
require(raster)
alt = getData('alt', country='CHE')
slope = terrain(alt, opt='slope')
aspect = terrain(alt, opt='aspect')
hill = hillShade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, main='Switzerland')
plot(alt, col=rainbow(25, alpha=0.35), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

As you say, very dark.

```
# after
grayalphas <- seq(-1,1,by=.01)^2*100
grayalphas[grayalphas==100] <- 99
plot(hill, col=paste0(grey(0:100/100),sprintf("%.2d",grayalphas)), legend=FALSE, main='Switzerland')

plot(alt, col=rainbow(25, alpha=0.35), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I set the gray alphas to have a parabolic shape, with minimum where the gray value is .5 and max of 99 at gray values of 0 or 1. If you choose something like this, you'll want to tinker with levels, etc, but it is easy to implement. Plus you'll want to put more effort than I did into the alphas, as mine are strictly numeric and not hex.

[Edit] I found a nifty function for adding alphas, `addTrans()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995683/any-way-to-make-plot-points-in-scatterplot-more-transparent-in-r/12996160#12996160) in Sacha Epskamp's answer. This keeps the parabola, but it ranges from 0 in the middle to 255 on the extremes.

```
grayalphas <- seq(-1,1,length=101)^2*255
plot(hill, col=addTrans(grey(0:100/100),grayalphas), legend=FALSE, main='Switzerland')
plot(alt, col=rainbow(25, alpha=0.35), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: As a packaged alternative to `addTrans`, there's `alpha` in the `scales` package.

Comment: @shujaa thanks for the tip, I didn't know that! That's something I need from time to time, will make note

Comment: I've found it very useful. It used to be in `ggplot2`, but then I panicked when I updated and it was missing! Was happy to realize those function were just getting more appropriately grouped. But now I remember that @BenBolker once pointed me to `?adjustcolor`, which is loaded by default and can do the same job (and more).