# plot hillshade in tmap

Tags: r, raster, tmap

I would like to plot a raster with [hillshading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487407/better-hillshading-for-map-plots-in-r) and add layers with `tmap`.

```
library(raster)
alt = getData('alt', country='CHE')
slope = terrain(alt, opt='slope')
aspect = terrain(alt, opt='aspect')
hill = hillShade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, main='Switzerland')
plot(alt, col=rainbow(25, alpha=0.35), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I would like to overlay roads etc. using `tmap`. How to make this work?

```
library(tmap)
tm_shape(hill) + tm_raster() + tm_shape(alt) + tm_raster()
```

is the same as

```
tm_shape(alt) + tm_raster()
```

The `tm_shape(hill) + tm_raster()` part gives warning message:

```
Variable "layer" contains positive and negative values, so midpoint is set to 0. Set midpoint = NA to show the full spectrum of the color palette.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tmap)  
tm_shape(hill) +
 tm_raster(palette = gray(0:100 / 100), n = 100, legend.show = FALSE)  +
  tm_shape(alt) +
  tm_raster(alpha = 0.5, palette = terrain.colors(25),
            legend.show = FALSE)
```

Thanks to Nowosad on the [tmap github page](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/244).