# Applying transparency to a vector of colors in plot function

Tags: string, r, concatenation, vectorization

I was trying to use `alpha` conversion to `col` argument in `plot` function. How do I do that without having to write `col=alpha(each_color,.5)` for `each_color`.

Is there a way to vectorize that?

Here is reproducible example:

```
set.seed(10)
mydata <- rnorm(100)
mycol <-c("#FDF6E3", "#B3E2CD", "#FDCDAC", "#CBD5E8", "#F4CAE4", "#E6F5C9", "#FFF2AE", "#F1E2CC", "#CCCCCC")
par(bg='gray30')
plot(mydata,col=mycol,pch=19,cex=3)
mycol_alpha <- paste0('alpha(\'',mycol,'\',.5)')
par(bg='white')
```

Is there a way to apply `mycol_alpha` to `plot` function directly or by some other way?

## update:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996136/1247080) one has the solution. My mistake, I thought the alpha `function` is in base `R`.
We need `library(scales)`

Solution:

```
set.seed(10)
mydata <- rnorm(100)
mycol <-c("#FDF6E3", "#B3E2CD", "#FDCDAC", "#CBD5E8", "#F4CAE4", "#E6F5C9", "#FFF2AE", "#F1E2CC", "#CCCCCC")
par(bg='gray30')
plot(mydata,col=scales::alpha(mycol,.5),pch=19,cex=3)
```

Comment: I don't believe so, but you did misspell `alpha` as `aphla`... Do you still see the transparency? Also, your use of `paste0` already *is* vectorized.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what the question is. I’m assuming `alpha` is a custom function. Is it not vectorised? Why not? Can it be vectorised by writing `Vectorize(alpha)`?

Comment: try `grDevices::adjustcolor` for a base solution

Comment: The base solution is most general, but `scales::alpha` is already vectorized (if that's the `alpha()` function you're using). With that function, you don't need the paste, just `mycol_alpha <- alpha(my_col, 0.5)`. Or `mycol_alpha <- adjustcolor(my_col, alpha.f = 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1):

vectorization is not your problem as noted by @Robert.

add

`transparency<-round(255*0.5)`  # 50% alpha

and try

`mycol_alpha <- paste0(mycol,as.hexmode(transparency))`

that should add transparency in `plot( ... , col=mycol_alpha , ...)`

no need for scales::alpha.