# Plot border and fill in a *single* shape?

Tags: r, plot

Usually I use base plotting (plot, points) to create symbols that may have colors for the border (col=...) and border (bg=...), but have to further process the graphs in Adobe Illustrator to fine-tune colors, opacity etc.

Unfortunately, R actually draws the border and the fill as two separate shapes on top of each other, which is somewhat difficult to handle if there are many data points.

Is there a way to plot border and fill in a *single* shape? Or to group these border shapes separately from the fill shapes from within R?

Comment: Why not use Adobe for fine-tuning the colors for sample plot, then apply colors in R? BTW, it is possible to set opacity using R see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995683/any-way-to-make-plot-points-in-scatterplot-more-transparent-in-r

Comment: Thanks, but I do extensively use graphical parameters (cex, colors incl. alpha, etc.) in R and then Adobe (Illustrator) for fine-tuning, which is nevertheless necessary, sometimes also for colors, symbol size etc. (e.g. after resizing for composite figures). And exactly for this fine-tuning the fact that each data point is represented by 2 objects (fill and border) seems troublesome... (otherwise I love R).