# Colour of line in R, go from white to black, depending on how many times we draw that line

Tags: r

Suppose that I create the following plot in `R`

```
plot(runif(100,0,5))
```

and I draw a vertical line at the point 50, and I do that 100 times

```
for(i in 1:100){
  abline(v = 50,col='red')
}
```

however, the results is exactly the same as running

```
abline(v = 50, col='red)
```

so it totally ignores that in the first case we plotted the line 100 times (so we give it more weight ideally darker red colour)

Is there a way in `R` to make the vertical line more thick depending on the times that we plot over it?

For example

```
abline(v = 50, col='red)
```

should correspond to a almost white red (if can say that)

```
for(i in 1:2){
abline(v = 50, col='red)
}
```

should correspond to a thicker red

```
for(i in 1:1000){
abline(v = 50, col='red)
}
```

should correspond to a dark red.

Can this even be done in `R`?

Comment: You need the line to be transparent - use the alpha parameter - zero for completely transparent (i.e. invisible), 1 for opaque. If you are overplotting 1000 times you will need alpha quite small.  See here for a way of doing it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995683/any-way-to-make-plot-points-in-scatterplot-more-transparent-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(runif(100,0,5))

n <- 100

for(i in n:1) {
  abline(v = 50, col = adjustcolor("red", alpha = 0.01 * (n - i) / n), lwd = i)
}
```

[image]

1. reverse your loop, as we plot line over line and start with the  widest one with the lowest transparency.
2. width of the line is set with `lwd`
3. set the alpha, but you need to normalize them between 0-1 but when you have a high n you need to adjust that value to very low values to see a difference (I used 0.01 as multiplier)